# how to test react-context using jest and enzyme where context is used inside constructor?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-context

I am using react-context for saving my data and accessing the data inside constructor as shown:

```
    class MyComponent extends Component {
      //constructor
      constructor(props, context) {
          super(props, context);

          const { testData } = this.context.storedData

          this.state={
          //maintained states
          }
      }
      //constructor ends
    }
```

I am trying to test the react-context using jest and enzyme framework but getting the error as below:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'testData ' of undefined

  25 |   constructor(props, context) {
  26 |     super(props, context);
> 27 |     const { testData  } = this.context.storedData
     |             ^
```

I have tried most of the solutions but nothing is working. I am looking for the perfect solution that suits my case.

Comment: wow, Legacy Context API. have never worked with it, may you consider moving to modern [Context API](https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Have never worked with Legacy Context and [its doc page](https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html) is rather poor. To test component that relies on context you have to pass that context, and there are few options.

1. Enzyme's `mount()`/`shallow()` provides [second argument `options`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html#mountnode-options--reactwrapper) which may be used for passing context. But I'm not sure if it works for Legacy context

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />, { context: {storedData: {testData: 1} } });
```

2. Use additional wrapper to provide context:

```
function createWrapperForContext (contextData) {
  return class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    getChildContext() {
      return contextData;
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  };
}
....
const ContextWrapper = createWrapperForContext(testData);
const elementWrapper = mount(<ContextWrapper><YourComponent /></ContextWrapper>)
```

If it's possible prefer moving to modern Context API, it's much more handful.

PS why do you need accessing `context` in constructor? If you worked with it in `render()` instead you would never worry about "context has been updated but `render()` still refers to old values".

Comment: Thanks for the solution @skyboyer
I have tried this but didn't work for me.

What solved my problem was: I imported the required context in test.js file and wrote test as: 
`test("render", () => {
    const props = {
      //props we need to pass
    }
    const contextData = {
      //context data we need to pass
    }
    const wrapper = mount(<ContextName.Provider value={contextData}>
        <ComponentName {...props} /></ContextName.Provider>)
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, passing options with context property will fix even for legacy context.

Suppose that we have `color` context https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html.

The test will be:

```
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component = ShallowWrapper<MyComponentProps>;

  // This will test the default color value
  it('should render with default context', () => {
    component = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>);

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  // testing with different context
  it('should render with context', () => {
    component = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />, {
      context: {
        color: 'red', // you still give it the default value.
      },
    });

    component.setContext({ color: 'purple' });
    component.instance().forceUpdate(); // you could call also render from instance
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```